# How does the "tail" command's "-f" parameter work?

Tags: command-line, monitoring, tail

```
$ tail -f testfile
```

the command is supposed to show the latest entries in the specified file, in real-time right? But that's not happening. Please correct me, if what I intend it to do is wrong...

I created a new file "aaa" and added a line of text and closed it. then issued this command (first line):

```
$ tail -f aaa
xxx
xxa
axx
```

the last three lines are the contents of the file aaa. Now that the command is still running (since I used `-f`), I opened the file aaa via the GUI and started adding a few more lines manually. But the terminal doesn't show the new lines added in the file.

What's wrong here? The `tail -f` command only shows new entries if they are written by system only? (like log files etc)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

From the `tail(1)` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tail):

> ```
>    With  --follow  (-f),  tail  defaults to following the file descriptor,
>    which means that even if a tail’ed file is renamed, tail will  continue
>    to  track  its  end.   This  default behavior is not desirable when you
>    really want to track the actual name of the file, not the file descrip-
>    tor (e.g., log rotation).  Use --follow=name in that case.  That causes
>    tail to track the named file  in  a  way  that  accommodates  renaming,
>    removal and creation.
> ```

Your text editor is renaming or deleting  the original file and saving the new file under the same filename. Use `-F` instead.

Comment: worked! So, I can use `$ tail -F filename` command all the time instead of `$ tail -f filename` right?

Comment: *If* that's your intended behavior. There *may* be cases where you want to follow by descriptor instead of filename, but to be fair I haven't come across many of those.

Comment: `lsof` can show this happening - for example `lsof -Fpcftni` would show that the inode being followed by `tail` is no longer the same one that the editor has open.

Answer (score 13):

Your editor has its own buffer for the file. When you modify the text in the editor, nothing is written to the file itself.

When you save your changes, chances are that the editor simply deletes the old file and create a new one. `tail -f` will still be connected to the deleted file, so it won't show anything new.

Comment: The editor overwrite the file, the logs append the text. This maybe be the problem.

Comment: Yes, I did mean the same that you :)

Answer (score 8):

`tail` "refresh" each 1 second by default, not realtime.

Try with this (you need bash4):

- Open 2 terminals.
- In the first terminal execute `touch ~/output.txt` and `tail -f ~/output.txt`.
- In the second terminal execute `for i in {0..100}; do sleep 2; echo $i >> ~/output.txt ; done`
- Look at the output of tail in the first terminal.

Comment: Did you mean `echo $i >> ~/output.txt`? Also, this answer misses the point of the question.

Comment: Yes, I corrected the fail while you wrote the comment :) . My answer is only a test for the problem _The tail -f command only shows new entries if they are written by system only?_

Comment: @Juan: Nowadays, on linux, `tailf` has a inotify based implementation. So it will refresh in realtime.

Comment: Yes for `tailf`, but `tail` uses inotify?. I didn't know `tailf`. The manpage of tail show the default of 1 second for `-s`.

Comment: Yes, `tail` followed and is now using inotify too when available. `tailf` is not polling at all, just sleeping, when there is no activity on the file. `tail -f` shows some activity (see `strace` output).

Comment: While your example is correct, it's not the correct answer for this situation - as others noted, it's most likely the editor doing a rename to a backup file and then creating a new file with the same name.

Comment: @Aaron: I did a similar comment in the answer of Stéphane.